# Eclipse CDT failure to debug in Ubuntu 11.10, throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I've recently done a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, installing the latest version of Eclipse CDT. I'm trying to debug an existing C++ project with makefiles and Eclipse project files generated by CMake. Upon attempting to debug (with all of the correct settings given in the Debug Configuration), the launch fails with error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching mops-app".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This does not occur when trying to debug a minimal Hello World project. The project could be successfully debugged on Ubuntu 11.04 with the latest version of Eclipse CDT. The java version on my machine is:

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

And the Eclipse output from trying to launch the debug configuration is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2011-10-31 11:50:24.211
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching mops-app".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.getSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.getSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1848)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.getSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1848)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.setSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.initializeSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.initialize(CDebugTarget.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.<init>(CDebugTarget.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.CDIDebugModel$1.run(CDIDebugModel.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2326)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.CDIDebugModel.newDebugTarget(CDIDebugModel.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.internal.LocalCDILaunchDelegate.launchLocalDebugSession(LocalCDILaunchDelegate.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.internal.LocalCDILaunchDelegate.launchDebugger(LocalCDILaunchDelegate.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.internal.LocalCDILaunchDelegate.launch(LocalCDILaunchDelegate.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was associated with upgrading the version of CMake. CMake 2.8.5 generated 'Subproject' entries in the Eclipse `.cproject` and `.project` files. For some reason, CMake by default told Eclipse to ignore the Subproject paths, thus confusing Eclipse's indexer when it tried to debug code.

The problem is easily resolved by commenting-out the `<linkedResources>` entry of the `.project` file, e.g.

```
<!--link>
    <name>[Subprojects]/MOPS</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <location>/home/user/mops-c-Git/src/mopsc</location>
</link-->
```

and commenting-out the Subproject portion `<pathentry>` entry of the `.cproject` file, e.g.

```
<!--pathentry kind="src" path="MOPS"/>
<pathentry excluding="MOPS/|**/CMakeFiles/" kind="out" path=""/-->
```

Comment: ah Ha ! this solved my problem too, but I had manually created a linked resource which was confusing the debugger, removed, works , now awesome!

Comment: @iondiode Yes this is indeed due to linked resources. I found another fix if you still need linked resources, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have selected the executable to run in the Run/Run or Run/Debug menu.

Comment: Checked this, not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (Ubuntu 14.04, SBT 13.1.0) - launching Debugger caused a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Checking the log by starting Eclipse with `eclipse-nios2 -consoleLog`, I had similar entries:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.getSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1843)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.getSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1864)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.getSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1864)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.setSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.initializeSourceLookupPath(CDebugTarget.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.initialize(CDebugTarget.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.core.model.CDebugTarget.<init>(CDebugTarget.java:279)
```

I believe the cause is the same; I found another fix and wanted to share it for completeness.

I have linked resources in my project, and the log made me suspect they were the cause. I had linked the resources with `Import->General->File system->[... Create links in workspace...]`.

I removed these links and instead linked to the sources by `Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->[tab] Source Location->Link folder...`.

This made the Debugger run fine without complaining.